# What counts as a factive verb in terms of presupposition triggers?

Tags: semantics, presupposition

Though words like *knew* or *realised* are commonly know factive verbs that trigger presupposition. Does verbs like *enjoyed, paid, looking forward, commended* and *delighted* also count as factive verbs which trigger presuppositions?

For example,
***Mark paid Debbie for publishing the book*** - the presupposition is clearly *Debbie published the book*. But does the *paid* acts as a a factive verb and presupposes the complement clause, or is it just semantic knowledge of the word *paid*, determine what should be assumed.

Or would the above example not be a presupposition at all?

Thank You.

From the book *Semantics* by Saeed, some dependent clauses can trigger presuppositions, so in the example, the presuppositional clause "for publishing the book" can be the trigger. However, I am unsure about this.

Comment: Semantics is not my field, but given that “Mark paid Debbie to publish the book” does **not** presuppose that Debbie in fact published the book (she may have just taken the money and run), I’d say at the least it would have to be the specific construction _pay [sb.] for [gerund]_ that could be seen as factive.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the answer and apologies if the example sentence was a bit unclear. However, if it say "Mark paid Debbie 'for' publishing the book", therefore would the use of 'for' mean that the book was already published? Thus the money was paid after. Would that mean a presupposition would still exist? Thanks again.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There is a clear semantic difference between "Mark paid Debbie **to** publish the book." and "Mark paid Debbie **for** publishing the book." and the difference *is* that with "for" and the participle, there is a presupposition that the action has been done, and with "to", it is presupposed that it hasn't, but whether "pay" is a factive verb or not, I don't know.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM Yes, that’s pretty much exactly what I said (I don’t know if it would count as a factive verb or not either – but if it does, then surely only in the _for_ construction, not the _to_ construction).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I greatly misunderstood your first comment, sorry.

Comment: Here's a [list of common presupposition triggers](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf) ("factive" only applies to verbal triggers) from Levinson.

Comment: Thank you very much jlawler.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Apologies for my reply to your comment, as I have seem to greatly misunderstood your comment.